# How to add a library in drupal 6 into a module file ( to run a slideshow created by flexslider )

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6

I'd like to run flexslider in drupal 6.

The module version is 7 and greater so I will make my own module to run the javascript for a slideshow. I don't need administrator control so it's just a matter of including the appropriate .js and .css files (i am not sure) into my module.

I'm not sure where in the module, those files are supposed to be added. Usually module files have at least a menu section and a page arguments section. Where would the included files go?

Comment: Your question can use a bit of clarification. Do you want to display a block? A content type? Which module's version is "7 and greater", since you seem to be talking Drupal 6?

Comment: I'd like to make a module that has css and javascript in it. Displaying a block is not an issue because there are tutorials ont hat process.

Answer (score 1):

I just added flexslider onto my Drupal 6 site, but I did so in the theme.  There are two parts to adding flexslider, the first is adding the flexslider code (CSS & JS) to the page, and the second is changing the markup Drupal outputs so that flexslider can target it correctly.

@pamatt was correct to ask for clarification on your first question.  You have not told us which part of Drupal you would like to use to generate the markup that flexslider will target: a block, a view, fields? A module can provide any (or all) of these things, but how it is done is different.

I added FlexSlider in my theme, as follows:

- First, I added the jQuery update module (to update jQuery to 1.3.2).
- I downloaded FlexSlider 1.8 from https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/tree/flexslider1 since that is the newest version that will work with jQuery 1.3.2
- in my info file, I added the CSS and JS (and of course put these files in these folders)

  ```
  stylesheets[all][]   = css/flexslider.css
  scripts[]            = js/jquery.flexslider.js
  ```
- in the head of my `page.tpl.php` file I added the code to hook up my slider:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    });
  </script>
  ```

(In your case, if you only want the slider on your home page, you could put this code into your `page--front.tpl.php` file instead.)

I chose to use a view to generate my output, so I also overrode the output of two template files, `views-view--featured.tpl.php` and `views-view-unformatted--featured.tpl.php`.  This is where I added the markup recommended by flexslider:

```
    <div class="flexslider">  <!-- change class in the outer template from view-content -->

      <ul class="slides">  <!-- add a UL into the inner template -->
        <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
        <li>  <!-- this LI replaces a div in the inner template -->
          <?php print $row; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>

    </div>  <!-- this div is in the outer template -->
```

Hope that helps the next person!

Answer (score 0):

You could add js at you theme's info file. For that edit your theme's info file and add this line scripts[] = 'custom.js'
 Or 
 you can use drupal_add_js function from your module to add js file

to add library copy the library and paste in the library folder

Comment: How can I ensure that the javascript will ONLY load for the main page?

Comment: I have to check but i believe this was something i tried. one sec!

Comment: i also believe i wrote that i did put drupal_add_js in the module, and that did NOT work. thanks